# Where can I set the value for authConfig.getUsernamePasswordEnabled

Tags: community

In the out-of-box Salesforce lightning component, I could see this configuration. But have no idea where we can setup this value for the  `getUsernamePasswordEnabled`. Any thought?

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean getIsUsernamePasswordEnabled() {
    Auth.AuthConfiguration authConfig = getAuthConfig();
    return authConfig.getUsernamePasswordEnabled();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure Auth Providers by going to Settings > Auth Providers.  There are a couple steps you need to take before you set up your provider(s) though.  Take a look here for details:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_sfdc.htm&type=0

Comment: I dont see any Registraion Handler in the Auth Provider that was listed in my org. I have been getting test class failures in my LigtningLoginFormController